# calabash issue with UIAlertView in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview, functional-testing, calabash

After iOS 7 We had an issue with UIAlertView verification using calabash.

for now I'm able to detect the alert message using

```
wait_for_elements_exist(["view:'_UIModalItemRepresentationView'"], :timeout => 20)
query("view:'_UIModalItemRepresentationView' label marked:'#{text}'",).empty?
```

I got the idea from https://gist.github.com/seanoshea/7613671

But previously (in iOS 6) we were able to detect the message and title clearly like this

```
title = query("view:'UIAlertView'",:title).first
msg = query("view:'UIAlertView'",:message).first
```

Is there any way that we can do the same in iOS7 ? "frank" guys do the same I think https://github.com/moredip/Frank/pull/262.

Note: [jmoody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047304/jmoody?tab=answers&sort=newest) Plese help us with this iOS 7 alerts in calabash automation.

Comment: We are aware of this issue.  It is (we believe) a bug in UIAutomation.  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/215 We recommend that you file a radar.  In the meantime the code that [Chathura Palihakkara](http://stackoverflow.com/users/634678/chathura-palihakkara) posted appears to be the work around.  Although he gets -1 for CamelCase in ruby... ;)

Comment: Sorry for CamelCase. This was the first time I met ruby :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I have been using this solution. If anyone face the same issue can use this until we have a good solution.

```
Then /^I should see empty email alert$/ do
  is_alert_exist_with_text("Email cannot be empty.")
  sleep(0.5)
  touch_alert_button("OK")
end
```

######## define the functions

```
def touch_alert_button(button)
  btn = query("view:'_UIModalItemTableViewCell' label marked:'#{button}'").first.empty?
  if (btn)
    screenshot_and_raise "button not found '#{button}'"
  else
    touch("view:'_UIModalItemTableViewCell' label marked:'#{button}'").first
    sleep(0.2)
  end
end

def is_alert_exist_with_text(text)
  unless query("view:'_UIModalItemRepresentationView' label marked:'#{text}'",).empty?
    return true
  else
    screenshot_and_raise "could not find the text '#{text}' in alert view"
  end
end
```

Further more...

```
def is_alert_exist_with_title_and_message(title, message)
  elements = query("view:'_UIModalItemRepresentationView' label", 'text')
  buttons = query("view:'_UIModalItemTableViewCell' label", 'text')
  textLabels = elements - buttons

  if (textLabels.count == 2)
    screenshot_and_raise "Alert Title '#{title}' not found" unless (textLabels[0].eql? title)
    screenshot_and_raise "Alert Message '#{message}' not found" unless (textLabels[1].eql? message)
  else
    screenshot_and_raise "Argument error...isAlertExistWithTitleAndMessage function"
  end
end
```